# Initialize a template object within a class (c++)

Tags: c++, class, templates, eigen

I want to denfine a class based on the Eigen library:

header file:

```
#include <Eigen>

using namespace Eigen;

class MatrixV{
    public:
        MatrixV(double mu, double omega, double delta, double size);
        Eigen::MatrixXd getV();
    private:
        Eigen::MatrixXd V;
        Eigen::JacobiSVD<Eigen::MatrixXd, Eigen::NoQRPreconditioner> svd(V, ComputeFullU | ComputeFullV);
};
```

cpp-file:

```
MatrixV::MatrixV(double mu, double omega, double delta, double size){
    Eigen::MatrixXd V = MatrixXd::Random(3,3)
}

Eigen::MatrixXd MatrixV::getV(){
    return V;
}
```

By compiling that code, my compiler gives me the following errors:

```
MatrixV.h:14:68: error: 'V' is not a type
   Eigen::JacobiSVD<Eigen::MatrixXd, Eigen::NoQRPreconditioner> svd(V,ComputeFullU | ComputeFullV);

MatrixV.h:14:71: error: 'ComputeFullU' is not a type
   Eigen::JacobiSVD<Eigen::MatrixXd, Eigen::NoQRPreconditioner> svd(V, ComputeFullU | ComputeFullV);

MatrixV.h:14:84: error: expected ',' or '...' before '|' token
   Eigen::JacobiSVD<Eigen::MatrixXd, Eigen::NoQRPreconditioner> svd(V, ComputeFullU | ComputeFullV);
                                                                              So the main problem seems to be the line 
Eigen::JacobiSVD<Eigen::MatrixXd, Eigen::NoQRPreconditioner> svd(V, ComputeFullU | ComputeFullV);
```

but I just copy-pasted it from http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1JacobiSVD.html and I also don't understand why he expects type names in the ()-brackets anyway. Do you have any Ideas? Thanks a lot!

Comment: It's a method declaration, you must put the types. It's not a function call with parameters.

Comment: Thanks man, that helped allready a lot. Do you also know, what to do with the '|' token?

Comment: @FuriousCpp The vertical line is the Bit OR operator.

Comment: Yes I know, but why doesn't the compiler like it? In the example of http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1JacobiSVD.html it works totaly fine.

Comment: Decalaration and definition are differnet. In Class decalaration, you need to decalare only. Just use 
Eigen::JacobiSVD< MatrixType, QRPreconditioner >::JacobiSVD svd in class, and then later use JacobiSVD::compute(const MatrixType&) to compute.

Comment: You are redeclaring `V` within the constructor: `Eigen::MatrixXd V `. Remove the `Eigen::MatrixXd` portion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error messages:

```
MatrixV.h:14:68: error: 'V' is not a type
   Eigen::JacobiSVD<Eigen::MatrixXd, Eigen::NoQRPreconditioner> svd(V,ComputeFullU | ComputeFullV);

MatrixV.h:14:71: error: 'ComputeFullU' is not a type
   Eigen::JacobiSVD<Eigen::MatrixXd, Eigen::NoQRPreconditioner> svd(V, ComputeFullU | ComputeFullV);

MatrixV.h:14:84: error: expected ',' or '...' before '|' token
   Eigen::JacobiSVD<Eigen::MatrixXd, Eigen::NoQRPreconditioner> svd(V, ComputeFullU | ComputeFullV);
```

are all caused by the same issue. The compiler thinks you're declaring a function, but it looks like you want to declare a variable `svd`. What you should do is to remove the parenthesis, and move it to the constructor:

```
#include <Eigen>

using namespace Eigen;

class MatrixV{
    public:
        MatrixV(double mu, double omega, double delta, double size);
        Eigen::MatrixXd getV();
    private:
        Eigen::MatrixXd V;
        Eigen::JacobiSVD<Eigen::MatrixXd, Eigen::NoQRPreconditioner> svd;
};
```

And change the constructor:

```
MatrixV::MatrixV(double mu, double omega, double delta, double size) {
    V = MatrixXd::Random(3,3)
    svd.compute(V, ComputeFullU | ComputeFullV);
}
```